# How can I heat up a separatory flask?

Tags: home-experiment

I currently am working on a vacuum brewing system for coffee (which is not super useful but pretty cool I have to say) such as this one (image).

[image: Text]

However I wondered if there was a way of pouring the coffee from the Florence flask directly to a mug? I'm thinking of using a separatory funnel instead of the Florence flask but can't seem to find any way of heating it up, is that a good option? By the way I'm still a high school student who likes chemistry.

Thanks a lot, Hugo

EDIT - more precise :

[image: Text]

This is one of the way I was thinking of doing it. On the picture :

- 1 is a Florence flask where I would heat up the water that would go directly into 2
- 2 is a beaker where the water would brew with coffee

When I turn the heat down, the brewed coffee should come back into the Florence flask 1.

However, to pour the coffee into the mug, I would have to manually pour the coffee from the Florence Flask. I therefore am looking for an option to move the coffee directly to the mug.

At that point, I thought of a separatory funnel - which probably isn't a chemically sound way of doing it - (terribly) drawn on the picture. But obviously I need a way of heating the separatory funnel.

My question is : is using a separatory funnel a good option to move around the coffee, if not is there an easier/better way? If it is, how can I effectively heat a separatory funnel?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are **heating mantles**, such as these t Fisher: https://www.seco.us/2582254/Product/Glas-Col-O-Series-Fabric-60deg-Funnel-Heating-Mantle-115-V-40-w . However, perhaps Cory Doctorow can convince you of the virtues of *cold brewed* coffee: https://boingboing.net/2013/07/20/cheap-easy-no-mess-cold-brew.html

Comment: if want it to look science-y and stuff and you were down to create some mechanical apparatus to move things around, perhaps you could get creative and use a retort flask (you can get them used sometimes for an OK price, I think) but I'm a little confused about what direction everything in your ideal apparatus goes so maybe try clarifying your proposed system for better insight.

Comment: @thelocalsage hey, thanks for your help. I edited the post to be more precise, see if it helps. Also don't get how the retort flask can be used here, could you explain more about it?

Comment: Your setup is not clear. Where is the coffee powder ? In 1 or in 2 ? Why is the bridge full of a red liquid ? Will you heat up or cool down flask 1 ? Why do you call mug a beaker ? Why do you heat up both containers 1 and 2 ? Why do you want to put a separator flask ? And where ?

Comment: Cool project. Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mECCEQllg5Y), his setup is very close to yours and he uses tongs for grabbing the neck of the Florence for transfer to the cup.

Comment: @Maurice the coffee powder is in 2: the beaker. When heated up in the Florence Flask 1, the water will go to the beaker 2 where it will brew with the coffee. When I stop the heating, the brewed coffee located in 2 will go to 1 because of the vacuum. This is the red/brownish liquid in the bridge. That's the basic system. My point is I want to "upgrade it" so that once the coffee is in the flask, I can move it to my mug. This is why I thought of a separatory funnel, so that I could just turn the tap and pour the coffee in my mug. Hope you get it, sorry if my explanations are confusing

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Thanks for the video, the tong does work just fine but I wonder if there is a way of not having to manipulate that much for the transfer. Anyways thanks!

Comment: @Hugosh Understood. Maybe a side arm round bottom? Although I have to admit it's not clear to me how you'd get the coffee to flow out of the side arm without some suction. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @Hugosh i don't believe there are great ways of heating separatory flasks simply because they don't tend to be used in situations that require heating. and they tend to have plastic stopcocks that could melt at higher temperatures...i suggested the retort flask as a possibility because if it was mounted on a rotational mechanism you could plug the top once done and use the arm as a spout but that may mess with the vacuum suction and it may be a bit too complex... but it would be science-y lol.

Comment: @hugosh i have an idea: what if the tube instead of being a single tube had a closable branch in the middle (like a stopcock) that fed out into your cup. you would prepare the coffee as normal, and once it's brewed and you begin the cooling process at 1 you wait for the coffee to travel back up the tube. Once the coffee reaches and fills the stopcocked prong and a little of it has begun to dribble back to 1, you open the stopcock and begin to let coffee out. the coffee forms a seal at the stopcock so the pressure differential isn't compromised, and the extra prong acts as a siphon. thoughts?

Comment: @localsage that does sound very cool and (kind of) easy to make. However, I gotta say I don't completely understand the apparatus. So if I recap, there would be a stopcock in the middle of the tube. Once the coffee is brewed and starts coming back to 1, I open the stopcock which leads the coffee to the cup? I don't get what's the prong part. Sorry for the loss of time, but I'm wondering if you could do a 2-second drawing on Paint or whatever because I really don't get it all here. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK I love this coffee setup and I want one. My suggestion might be too expensive, but if you could get your hands on a schlenck flask, you could heat and dispense from that. It still requires tipping it, but you wouldn't have to take the top off if the tube connecting 1 and 2 were flexible. Or you could dispense through a cannula. That's assuming that I'm understanding the pressure changes correctly when the coffee comes back over.